# Do I need Solr or ElasticSearch to create a REST API for a Lucene DB?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I've created a Lucene DB and everything works fine. Now I need a REST API to access its contents. Solr and ElasticSearch offer this as far as I understood it. But is it really an advantage to  use them? My idea was: "Dude, simply do it yourself with your favorite MVC Framework". The thing is, that the DB is on a stand-alone server where I could actually use Solr or ElasticSearch without downsides and wouldn't need to program the API myself (only that I have to dive into these libraries, which would be fun).

So the question is: If you don't need any of the capabilities of Solr and ElasticSearch besides the REST API, is it still reasonable to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally following your question but I would say, from experience, that the Solr API is really nice to work with.  I've also used the Elastic Search API and again it's great.  If you can pick one and stay with it, either should perfectly meet your needs.

However, if there's a chance you might change the underlying engine then that's when your own API will pay dividends.  Properly engineered, you'd be able to switch out the engine without affecting the interface.

Given a choice, I'd still pick the Solr API, it's a well engineered solution.